# Android list view is not displaying when I use on click view listener

Tags: android

I want to add on click Listener to my list view. But when I add on click listener to launch a new Intent, the list view vanishes.

I had added list view.setonItemclicklistener and failed.

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fi.com.cgulf" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DisplayActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity android:name=".DetailsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

HomeActivity.java

```
package fi.com.cgulf;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import fi.com.cgulf.adapter.MyArrayAdapter;
import fi.com.cgulf.model.MyDataModel;
import fi.com.cgulf.parser.JSONParser;
import fi.com.cgulf.utils.InternetConnection;
import fi.com.cgulf.utils.Keys;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ListView listView;
    public ArrayList<MyDataModel> list;
    public MyArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ImageButton img1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        ImageButton img2= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
            new GetDataTask().execute();

        } else {
        }
    }
    public void onClickb1(View view)
    {
        Intent homeIntent =new Intent(HomeActivity.this,DisplayActivity.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();
    }
    public void onClickb2(View view)
    {
        Intent homeIntent =new Intent(HomeActivity.this,DisplayActivity.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();
    }

class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    int jIndex;
    int x;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        x=list.size();

        if(x==0)
            jIndex=0;
        else
            jIndex=x;


        dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Please wait..");
        dialog.setMessage("Loading Data");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        /**
         * Getting JSON Object from Web Using okHttp
         */
        JSONObject jsonObject = JSONParser.getDataFromWeb();

        try {
            /**
             * Check Whether Its NULL???
             */
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                /**
                 * Check Length...
                 */
                if(jsonObject.length() > 0) {
                    /**
                     * Getting Array named "contacts" From MAIN Json Object
                     */
                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Keys.KEY_CONTACTS);

                    /**
                     * Check Length of Array...
                     */
                    int lenArray = array.length();
                    if(lenArray > 0) {
                        for( ; jIndex < lenArray; jIndex++) {

                            /**
                             * Creating Every time New Object
                             * and
                             * Adding into List
                             */
                            MyDataModel model = new MyDataModel();

                            /**
                             * Getting Inner Object from contacts array...
                             * and
                             * From that We will get Name of that Contact
                             *
                             */
                            JSONObject innerObject = array.getJSONObject(jIndex);
                            String name = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_NAME);
                            String country = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_COUNTRY);

                            /**
                             * Getting Object from Object "phone"
                             */
                            //JSONObject phoneObject = innerObject.getJSONObject(Keys.KEY_PHONE);
                            //String phone = phoneObject.getString(Keys.KEY_MOBILE);

                            model.setName(name);
                            model.setCountry(country);

                            /**
                             * Adding name and phone concatenation in List...
                             */
                            list.add(model);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            Log.i(JSONParser.TAG, "" + je.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        dialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Checking if List size if more than zero then
         * Update ListView
         */
    }
}
}
```

MyArrayAdapter.java

```
package fi.com.cgulf.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import fi.com.cgulf.R;
import fi.com.cgulf.model.MyDataModel;

public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyDataModel>  {

    List<MyDataModel> modelList;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    // Constructors
    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, List<MyDataModel> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        modelList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public MyDataModel getItem(int position) {
        return modelList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activitysection, parent, false);
            vh = ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
            view.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        MyDataModel item = getItem(position);

        vh.textViewName.setText(item.getName());
        vh.textViewCountry.setText(item.getCountry());

        return vh.rootView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public final RelativeLayout rootView;

        public final TextView textViewName;
        public final TextView textViewCountry;

        private ViewHolder(RelativeLayout rootView, TextView textViewName, TextView textViewCountry) {
            this.rootView = rootView;
            this.textViewName = textViewName;
            this.textViewCountry = textViewCountry;

        }
        public static ViewHolder create(RelativeLayout rootView) {
            TextView textViewName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            TextView textViewCountry = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCountry);
            return new ViewHolder(rootView, textViewName, textViewCountry);
        }

        }
    }
```

DisplayActivity.java

```
package fi.com.cgulf;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import fi.com.cgulf.adapter.MyArrayAdapter;
import fi.com.cgulf.model.MyDataModel;


public class DisplayActivity extends HomeActivity {
    public static ArrayList<MyDataModel> list1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list1=list;
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, list1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("pos", position);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

At first without the onitem click listener there wasn't any problems on displaying the list view. Later when I add the click option with an intent to another activity, the list view has gone..

Comment: The List View vanishes because after you startActivity in the onItemClick event, you call finish() which closes the current activity (DisplayActivity).  If you don't want the list to disappear, then do not call finish.  When the DetailsActivity calls finish(), then the focus will go back to your List View.

Answer (score 0):

First at all, you should read about [Android back stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack).
After you click on the item you start `DetailsActivity` then you finish `DisplayActivity`, so when you are on `DetailsActivity` and click back you will back to the activity before `DisplayActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with interface callback

in your adapter:

```
// declare interface object  
private CallBackListner listner;
// Constructors
public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, List<MyDataModel> objects, 
                                               CallBackListner listner) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    modelList = objects;
    this.listner = listner;
}
```

Now in your getView method in adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder vh;
    if (convertView == null) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activitysection, parent,   
                                                                  false);
        vh = ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
        view.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    MyDataModel item = getItem(position);

    vh.textViewName.setText(item.getName());
    vh.textViewCountry.setText(item.getCountry());
    vh.textViewName.setOnClickListner(....
    // call the interface callback
    listner.onCallback(position);
    } 
    return vh.rootView;
}
```

Now in your DisplayActivity initialize you interface and also define the interface as inner interface of HomeActivity:

```
public class DisplayActivity extends HomeActivity {
public static ArrayList<MyDataModel> list1;
private CallBackListner listner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // initialize the interface here
    listner = new CallBackListner({
    @override
    public void onCallback(int pos){
      // here you get the current position of the item, do your stuff

    }
    })
}
public interface CallBackListner{
 void onCallback(int pos);
}
```

And also I assume there may be wrong with the Parent class. can you please add the XML where you add the onClick attribute i.e. onClickb1 and onClickb2?